# Duda sobre impresion de arraylist

Tags: java

Quería saber como puedo imprimir un arraylist bidimensional con el siguiente formato, teniendo en cuenta que las X son personas con edad mayor de 18, las C personas menores de edad y los ? asientos vacíos. La clase persona ya esta creado con sus correspondientes setters y getters ademas de los atributos(edad, genero...) y el arraylist es de 5 columnas y filas introducidad mediante un método setRows(), los elementos del Array son de tipo Persona:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 0 X X ? ? ? 
 1 X X C ? ? 
 2 ? X ? ? ? 
 3 X X ? C X 
 4 C X X X X
```

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, no se sabe si lo que quieres decir es que los elementos del array son instancias de `Persona`¿?  Muestra lo que has intentado y dinos qué error tienes o qué no funciona bien.

Comment: Si, los elementos del Array son de tipo Persona

Comment: Ok, pero no se entiende lo que quieres hacer, tampoco se sabe cómo se llaman los métodos de la clase `Persona` ni cómo creas el array. Sería bueno que muestres lo que estás intentando para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Para no copiar toda las clases te digo, los métodos que se deberían usar son un getAge(), este de la clase Persona para sacar la edad de cada persona y las constantes ADULT_CODE ("X"), CHILD_CODE("C") y EMPTY_CODE("?") (de la clase Controlador) , lo que busco es imprimir un mapa con las edades que hay en cada asiento, es decir, si en la fila 1 columna 1 hay alguien con 20 años , poner una X, si hay alguien con 13 una C y si no hay nadie un ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mas o menos quedaría así:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MapaAsientos {

    //este array de tipo char es para guardar los códigos X,C,?
    private static char[][] matrizCode =new char[Persona.getROWS()][Persona.getCOLUMNS()];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Persona(13).addPersonaAt(0, 0);
        new Persona(14).addPersonaAt(0, 1);
        new Persona(10).addPersonaAt(0, 2);
        new Persona(15).addPersonaAt(0, 3);
        new Persona(12).addPersonaAt(0, 4);
        new Persona(25).addPersonaAt(1, 0);
        new Persona(21).addPersonaAt(1, 1);
        new Persona(23).addPersonaAt(1, 2);
        new Persona(28).addPersonaAt(1, 3);
        new Persona(39).addPersonaAt(1, 4);
//        new Persona(16).addPersonaAt(2, 0);
//        new Persona(25).addPersonaAt(2, 1);
//        new Persona(17).addPersonaAt(2, 2);
//        new Persona(24).addPersonaAt(2, 3);
//        new Persona(45).addPersonaAt(2, 4);
        new Persona(30).addPersonaAt(3, 0);
        new Persona(19).addPersonaAt(3, 1);
        new Persona(18).addPersonaAt(3, 2);
        new Persona(14).addPersonaAt(3, 3);
        new Persona(11).addPersonaAt(3, 4);
        new Persona(16).addPersonaAt(4, 0);
        new Persona(9).addPersonaAt(4, 1);
        new Persona(36).addPersonaAt(4, 2);
        new Persona(22).addPersonaAt(4, 3);
        new Persona(50).addPersonaAt(4, 4);

        cargarMatrizCode();
        printMatrizCode();

    }
    //llenamos array matrizCode en función de lo que hay en array matrizPersona
    private static void cargarMatrizCode(){

        for (int i = 0; i < Persona.getROWS(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Persona.getCOLUMNS(); j++) {
                if (Persona.getMatrizPersona()[i][j] == null)
                    matrizCode[i][j] =Controlador.getEMPTY_CODE();
                else if (Persona.getMatrizPersona()[i][j].getAge() < Controlador.getLIMIT_EDAD())
                    matrizCode[i][j] =Controlador.getCHILD_CODE();
                else matrizCode[i][j] =Controlador.getADULT_CODE();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void printMatrizCode(){
        String column ="# ";//el # es de relleno..+ espacio para que queden alineados
        String row;
        for (int i = 0; i < Persona.getROWS(); i++) {
            row ="";
            for (int j = 0; j < Persona.getCOLUMNS(); j++) {
                column +=j+" ";
                row +=matrizCode[i][j]+" ";//esto no es una asignación, sino concatenación  
            }
            //el if es para que imprima por única vez los índices de las columnas
            //ya que sale varias veces del for interno
            if(i == 0) System.out.println(column);
            System.out.println(i+" "+row);//imprime número de fila (i), espacio y fila
            //completa (row) que la fuí concatenando con todos los valores de la fila [i][0] hasta [i][4]
        }
    }
}
class Controlador{

    private static final char ADULT_CODE ='X';
    private static final char CHILD_CODE ='C';
    private static final char EMPTY_CODE ='?';
    private static final int LIMIT_EDAD =18;

    public static char getADULT_CODE() {
        return ADULT_CODE;
    }

    public static char getCHILD_CODE() {
        return CHILD_CODE;
    }

    public static char getEMPTY_CODE() {
        return EMPTY_CODE;
    }

    public static int getLIMIT_EDAD() {
        return LIMIT_EDAD;
    }
    public static void CargarMatrizCode(){

    }   
}
class Persona{

    private final static int ROWS =5;
    private final static int COLUMNS =5;
    private static Persona[][] matrizPersona =new Persona[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    private int age;

    public Persona(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static int getROWS() {
        return ROWS;
    }
    public static int getCOLUMNS() {
        return COLUMNS;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public static Persona[][] getMatrizPersona() {
        return matrizPersona;
    }
    public void addPersonaAt(int row, int column){
        matrizPersona[row][column] =this;
    }
}
```

En la **fila 0** puse **menores** de edad, en la **1** **mayores** y la **2** la comenté para que se muestren los asientos vacíos